# Android Unable to delete ImageView using implemented delete button

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

*** EDITED ***

```
public void btnTakePhotoClicked(View v) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

public void btnDeletePhotoClicked(View v) {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpecimenPhoto);
    iv.setImageDrawable(null);
    Toast.makeText(AddIncome.this, "Photo deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            cameraImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgSpecimenPhoto.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);
        }
    }

}
```

Everything works fine except for:

```
public void btnDeletePhotoClicked(View v) {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpecimenPhoto);
    iv.setImageDrawable(null);
    Toast.makeText(AddIncome.this, "Photo deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I'm not able to delete photo after pressing the button
Only the Toast "Photo Deleted" is working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhOaU.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "However when I press back, and go into the intent again"? Are you launching the same activity intent again?

Answer (score 1):

Paste this below code in your onCreate() method of activity. Your updated onCreate method should look like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.adddata); 
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpecimenPhoto);
    iv.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried adding this onCreate it doesnt work :(, I use this on public void to delete my image when button is pressed it works, but the data is persistent even after pressing back button. Only the EditText is cleared/reset

Comment: Provided in edit! Hope to have some leads! :) I would like how do I reset stored data in a layout whenever people go to that layout (only EditText is reset, not ImageView)

Comment: Please provide me the details of "Back" button click listener as well.

Comment: I did not implement that

Comment: "However when I press back, and go into the intent again" In this statement which "back" button are you referring to? I mean, phone's "back" button or the one which you have provided on your activity screen?

Comment: I believed its intent (adddata layout) back to another intent (main layout)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: I'm sorry for unclear comment.. Currently the ImageView is on adddata layout, when I press back it will go to main.layout. However when I press "+" (which brings the user to adddata layout), the ImageView still persists even though I've deleted the Image previously. I wish that everytime the user press "+" it will be a default adddata layout without any previous data.

Comment: So basically you have 2 different activities/Screen Main & AddData. Right?

Comment: Yes that's correct! :) Only my ImageView (from user camera) is not erased even thought user have pressed the backbutton

Comment: "Back" button you are referring to is the one which you have provided on your activity screen?